# How to select option value from the List box?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, appium-android

In our application most of the fileds embedded list box with input field, when we keep curses on the element ,it displays list and then we need to select value form the list

Environment: Selenium Webdriver,appium ,java

Html code:

```html
<div class="ant-select-selector" css="1" xpath="1"><span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_9_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_9_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_9_list_2" value="" id="rc_select_9" aria-expanded="true" style=""></span><span class="ant-select-selection-item" title="name">name</span></div>
```

what I have tried and what is the outcome:

```
WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ant-select-selection-search-input"));
        inputField.click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        WebElement dropdownEl = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.rc-virtual-list")));

        WebElement dropdownSelector = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.rc-virtual-list"));


        List<WebElement> allOptions = dropdownSelector.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-item-option-content']"));
        // Click on the dropdown selector to open the dropdown list
        String optionToSelect="Sachin";
        Integer listSize = allOptions.size();
        System.out.println("List:"+listSize);
        if (listSize > 0)
            for (WebElement el : allOptions) {
                if (dropdownSelector.getText().contains(optionToSelect)) {
                    el.click();
                    break;
                }
```

}
}

the above working on any element but I am facing one more issue here , I have same kind of multiple elements with matching 'ant-select-selection-search-input' property .

infact of each filed having a label but not sure how to capture and make sure that the specific elements belongs that label

now I need a solution to identify specific elements out of multiple elements

here updated html and what I observed id rc_select_9 is dynamically generating after we click on the element.

I am expecting some good solutions from here.

Tried different ways to select value but no luck,
could you please help me how can we select the desired value from the list .

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Comment: @JeffC I am not sure but I have posted the source and what I am expecting here, if you can not understand may someone can who have knowledge on Selenium Webdriver to select option value

Comment: As I commented above, it's not about whether I have knowledge or not (and I do)... it's about the lack of info that you have provided for us to help you. Read the links I provided and improve your question.

Comment: I hope I have noe the enough info here, and might help to find solution below now also 

there are multiple elements each filed having similar properties like class only difference their corresponding before label will be different, for example Select Type: Dropdownbox with edit filed , Select Name: Dropdownbox wit edit field...

Answer (score 0):

Using WebDriverWait to wait until the dropdown options are visible.
Locating the desired option by its XPath (you may need to adjust the XPath based on your actual HTML structure).
Make sure to replace "Option Value" in the XPath with the actual value you want to select. If the dropdown options have unique attributes, you can modify the locator accordingly.

Comment: I did all these, but not working ..while selecting its not able to identify the value.
can you share the code according to you which works for you?